# I deleted one field from a split table and now I cannot see a continous form in my front end

Tags: ms-access

I wanted to make it so that I didn't always have to manually input an item code. So i deleted the field and tried linking my table to the autonumber id.

However, when i went to the subform that has the items i want to select, the dropdown combobox is no longer there.

I tried remaking the field and putting it in the same location but this has not helped.

I am wondering if I have to remake the form and queries or if it is possible to link the forms again and make it usable?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correction. I had to reset the keys to the original setting. After that, the sub form began to appear.